# how to organize a python module that scripts can be run as __main__ program?

Tags: python, import, code-organization

I'm starting a project in python, the code structure now as below:

```
project/
        __init__.py
        a.py
        b.py
        mainA.py
        utilities/
                   __init__.py
                   mainB.py
                   c.py
```

The `__init__` files are all blank.

I want to run `utilities/mainB.py` as a program(using something like `python main.py`), and mainB needs to import `a.py` and `b.py`. So I tried `from .. import a` and some other approaches, but the `import` failed. The error information is:

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

So here comes the questions:

1. how to fix `mainB.py` so it can be run as a main program?
2. `mainA.py` can be run as main program now, it also imports `a.py` and `b.py`(using `import a` and `import b`).
   I think the code structure may become more complex. Say, if `mainA.py` has to import a module from `project/some/directory`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Python's built-in module-running functionality (`python -m <module>`).

```
python -m project.utilities.mainB
```

This allows you to write mainB normally as part of the package, so relative and absolute imports will both work correctly.

For an in-depth discussion of this functionality, see [PEP-338](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/).

Answer (score 3):

See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python).  You have two options.  One is to use the `__package__` attribute as described in [PEP 366](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) to set the relative name of your modules.  The other is to execute your scripts as modules (using the `-m` flag to the interpreter) instead of running them directly as scripts.

Comment: PEP 366 says `Additional code that manipulates sys.path would be needed in order for direct execution to work without the top level package already being importable.` Could you please show me how based on my code structure?

Comment: Are you sure your top-level code isn't importable?  If your top-level code isn't importable (e.g., if you can't do `import project` and have it work) it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to make it a package at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should add 'project' dir in PYTHON_PATH and then, in mainB.py:

```
from project import a
```